# Excel C# Create Combobox

Tags: c#, excel, combobox, addition, worksheet

I am trying to take a cell in an excel sheet and add a combobox where I can add data and a select change event to it like a regular asp.net control. I know msdn has add Combobox to excel in their documentation but I dont understand what dlls are needed or how to set it up to just add the combobox to the cell. Please Help

Comment: How are you interacting with the document, and where (desktop? ASP page on the server?)

Comment: Im trying to interact with excel sheet that is made on the fly from an addin project. Thanks

Comment: I'm not a big C#+Excel person, but you can most likely find an approach using VBA which would be relatively easy to map to C# and the interop library. However I'm not at all clear on what you mean by "a select change event to it like a regular asp.net control".  There's not much in excel which seems "like" ASP.Net, though Excel does have event procedures, so maybe you could leverage those to do what you need.

Comment: I was able to create a c# excel project using the workbook project in visual studio and add a combobox to one of the cells, in that way I am able to use the events from the combobox like a asp.net or winforms control, I am just trying to figure out how to use this line Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.ComboBox comboBox1 = this.Controls.AddComboBox(range[A1], "comboBox1"); in a excel project that creates the excel sheet on the fly rather than create a Excel 2007 Workbook project and put it in the sheet startup. the this keyword refers to "Sheet1"

Comment: Sorry - I don't have any suggestions.